# Can I add more math constants to Spotlight search?

Tags: macos, spotlight

You can use `pi` to do calculations, but I also want to add `tau` and more math constants, is there a way to do this?

Comment: isn't tau 2xpi ?

Comment: Yeah but I also want others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight can only perform the functions listed in the `math` man page (type `man math` in Terminal to get a full list of functions). Adding a new constant like τ would likely require modifying a library.

Comment: Because the spotlight icon is calculator, I once thought that I can do something in the calc preference. Seems I was wrong.